# How to replace one array key value with another array index value?

Tags: php, arrays

```
$a=array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 3 );
$b=array ( [0] => Done [1] => Pending ) ;
```

I want somthing like this:

```
array([0]=>Done [3]=>Pending)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**array_replace()**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php)

```
$a = array( [0] => 0 [1] => 3 );
$b = array( [0] => Done [1] => Pending ) ;

$result = array_replace($a, $b);
```

Array replace, replaces all values of $a that have the same key in $b with $b's values.

Answer (score 6):

Use: [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/array_combine):

```
$result = array_combine($a, $b);
print_r($result); // => Array ( [0] => Done [1] => Pending )
```

[Demo.](https://eval.in/81445)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
 $a=array (0=>0,1=>3);
 $b=array (0=>'Done',1=>'Pending');
 $c= array_merge($a,$b);

echo "<br/> a: ";print_r($a); 
echo "<br/> b: ";print_r($b); 
echo "<br/> c: ";print_r($b);
```

OUTPUT :

a: Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 3 )

b: Array ( [0] => Done [1] => Pending )

c: Array ( [0] => Done [1] => Pending )

try it with online editor [Test your PHP code online, right here.]

http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Example also in http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 0):

If your two array sizes are same then try this:

```
$a =array( 0 => 0, 1 => 3 );  
$b=array ( 0 => "Done", 1 => "Pending" ) ;  

$result = array();  
for($i=0 ; $i < count($a);$i++){  
    $result[$a[$i]] =  $b[$i];  
}  
print_r($result);
```